# unable to archive and unarchive files using 7zip in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, 7zip

I have to do transfer files from one host to other so i have decided to go with zip (IONIC) but problem with that is it eat's lot of memory when it comes for larger file, so i have decided to go with 7Z dll. i had tried to achieve compress & Uncompress which works perfectly fine on my console after changing some settings (unchecked prefer-32 bit from https://blog.jongallant.com/2011/10/7-zip-dll-file-does-not-exist/).

but which fails on ASP.net application and i am getting "**Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error! Message: failed to load library.**" when i try to compress or uncompress.

the code what i have tried.

```
protected void btnCompress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dllPath = "";

            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                dllPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"7z\7z64.dll");
            }
            else
                dllPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"7z\7z.dll");

            var tmpPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(txtTempPath.Text, txtDir.Text);
            try
            {
                SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(dllPath);
                SevenZipCompressor sz = new SevenZipCompressor();
                sz.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Ultra;
                sz.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
                sz.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Default;
                sz.FastCompression = true;
                sz.CompressDirectory(tmpPath, tmpPath + "_7Zip.7z");
                //Directory.Delete(backupFolder, true);                
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Compressed successfully');</script>");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
                //throw ex;
            }
        }

        protected void btnExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var tmpPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(txtTempPath.Text, txt7z.Text);

                SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll");
                SevenZipExtractor zip = new SevenZipExtractor(tmpPath);
                zip.ExtractArchive(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tmpPath));

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Extracted successfully');</script>");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
            }
        }
```

please someone suggest a proper solution for this,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please ensure that your dllPath is correct. Also, check this blog post https://blog.jongallant.com/2011/10/7-zip-dll-file-does-not-exist/

Comment: yes dll exists in correct path. i have mentioned the link in my question

Comment: While debugging the code `if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)` returns true or false? I mean if it is failing for one environment (e.g. 64bit) try for other environment by forcibly setting the dllPath while debugging. If it work then it means the code is not loading the correct dll based on environment

Comment: i had tried to run with both 32bit and 64bit dll's but failing on both the occasions

Comment: I believe you have copied both 7z.dll and 7z64.dll in your project. Have you tried loading the 7z.dll from the `Program Files` path e.g. `C:\Program Files\7-Zip`.

Comment: yes i had tried that one as well, you can see that on extract functionality

Comment: i guess their is some environmental setting to be changed in asp.net project i'm sure i'm failing on that one only but unable to figure what i need to change

Comment: `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` is a wrong test. You should test process bitness, not OS bitness, as IIS supports both 64 and 32 bit web apps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @LexLi i have tried loading both 64bit and 32bit 7z dll and my os is 64bit but fails with both the dll's

Answer (score 0):

I think using   (Environment.Is64BitProcess) instead of Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)  will work if you have set correct dll path.Make sure that dll exists in that path.